# jquery function not stop

Tags: jquery, loops, intervals

I try to stop my function by clicking div, but function not stoped! What mistakes I made?
I try to change interval for repeating my function, but it's not work((
This is my code

```
Piano.anim = function(){
    var monitorGlich = true;
    var interval = 100;
    var $glich = $('.monitor-glich');
    if(monitorGlich){
        setInterval(function(e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $glich.addClass('active');
            },4000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $glich.removeClass('active');
            },1000);
        }, interval);
    }else{
        $glich.removeClass('active');
    }
    $(".monitor").click(function(){
        interval = 0;
        monitorGlich = false;
        console.log(interval);
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you got your code wrapped in a document.ready statement?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable (`myIntVal = 0;`) in global scope and use it inside your function as

```
myIntVal = setInterval(function(e) { 
    //...
}, 4000);
```

In `$(".monitor").click(...)` use something like

```
$(".monitor").click(function(){
    // ...
    clearInterval(myIntVal); // clears the timer so loop stops
});
```

So, `setInterval` will stop.